# Regex: delete everything between String and replace with other

Tags: regex, xml, sublimetext3

So I've been scratching my head over this one, I have over a thousand files that have different values between the strings

```
<lodDistances content="float_array">
    15.000000
    25.000000
    70.000000
    140.000000
    500.000000
    500.000000
  </lodDistances>
```

I need to replace those values with these

```
<lodDistances content="float_array">
  120.000000
  200.000000
  300.000000
  400.000000
  500.000000
  550.000000
</lodDistances>
```

I tried the following without any success

```
\ (?<=\<lodDistances content\=\"float_array\"\>)(.*)(?=\<\/lodDistances\>)
```

It seems to find it in regexr but not in a sublime text when I try to find it in files, I constantly get 0 results. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: It's just an XML file format

Comment: Try this `(?s)(?<=<lodDistances content="float_array">\n).*?(?=\n\s+<\/lodDistances>)`

Comment: @CarySwoveland, he mentioned that he was using sublime text editor to do the replacement

Comment: Still no matches :(

Comment: Just to be sure, did you check the Regular expression button in Sublime? Using this with the example data, I get a match `(?s)(?<=<lodDistances content="float_array">)(.*?)(?=</lodDistances\>)`

Comment: Yep that was the issue, thought I had it enabled. now to replace I just need to replace the values with the values without the first and last line ?

Comment: @DannyBelanger Then I think you can use the pattern of Daniel in the previous comment.

Comment: Figured It out, Just by replacing with the values only did it work. Thanks so much you guys saved me tons of work :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things that are wrong in your pattern:

- `\<` matches a leading word boundary position (as `\b(?=\w)`) and `\>` matches the trailing word boundary position (same as `\b(?<=\w)`). You wanted to match literal `<` and `>` chars, thus, you must NOT escape them
- There is no need matching a space before the first `<`
- Since you text is multiline, use either `(?s)`  inline modifier or `(?s:...)` modifier group to make `.` match across line breaks, or use a `[\s\S]` / `[\w\W]` / `[\d\D]` workaround
- Use a lazy dot pattern to stop matching at first occurrence of the trailing delimiter.

You may use

```
(?s)(<lodDistances content="float_array">\s*).*?(?=\s*</lodDistances>)
```

And replace with `${1}<new values>`. The curly braces are necessary as the `new values` are most likely numbers and without the braces, `$1n` (`n` stands for a digit here) will be parsed incorrectly (see [this YT video for a demo of what it is fraught with](https://youtu.be/QYzWATloxnw?t=167)).

See the demo below:

[image]

V

[image]

*Regex details*:

- `(?s)` - now, `.` matches line break chars, too
- `(<lodDistances content="float_array">\s*)` - Group 1 capturing `<lodDistances content="float_array">` text and then zero or more whitespaces
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars, but as few as possible
- `(?=\s*</lodDistances>)` - a positive lookahead that matches the location that is immediately followed with zero or more whitespaces and `</lodDistances>` text.

Note that `/` is not a special regex metacharacter, and since regex delimiter notation is not supported in Sublime Text, you do not have to ever escape it here.